# How to implement object oriented T-SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, oop

Kind of an open ended question.
Is it possible to somehow implement transactional SQL (SQL-Server) stored procedures in an object oriented paradigm?
So we can implement known design patterns in such stored procedures

Comment: It's also very abstract. Could you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course you can. Create process in some programming language and use only atomic and simple sql commands. Link of example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx .

Comment: @ColinMackay I am trying to implement Design Patterns and TDD on stored procedures. It is not possible with the current functional programming style.